# LaTeX Traditional Chinese fonts, numbers in PDF are not searchable

Tags: fonts, cjk, xelatex

Linux `xelatex` compile Chinese files with `xeCJK`.

Fonts `Noto Serif CJK TC` and `Noto Sans CJK TC` are able to cover traditional/simplified/pinyin.
However, the numbers in the text aren't searchable by PDF viewers (Evince 3.28.4, Adobe Reader 9, Atril 1.20.1). How to overcome it?

Other fonts like `WenQuanYi` failed with the Pinyin letter 'guǒ'.
And `AR PL` failed in the traditional Chinese letter '爲'.

```
\documentclass{article}
%% fontspec package requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}
\newfontfamily\wqyfamily{WenQuanYi Micro Hei}
\newfontfamily\ukai{AR PL UKai TW}
\newfontfamily\uming{AR PL UMing TW}

\begin{document}

%\normalfont default：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\rmfamily roman：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\sffamily sans serif：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\wqyfamily WenQuangYi：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\ukai AR PL UKai：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\uming AR PL UMing：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\ttfamily typewriter：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\mdseries medium：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\bfseries bold：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\upshape upright：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\itshape italic：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\slshape slanted：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\scshape Small Caps：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）

\em emphasized：繁體：因爲有120個蘋果。简体：因为有120个苹果（píng guǒ）


\end{document}
```

[image]

All Chinese related fonts I have:

```
Noto Sans CJK HK,Noto Sans CJK HK DemiLight
Noto Sans CJK KR,Noto Sans CJK KR Medium
Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP SemiBold
Noto Serif CJK TC,Noto Serif CJK TC Medium
WenQuanYi Micro Hei,文泉驛微米黑,文泉驿微米黑
AR PL UKai CN
Noto Serif CJK SC
Noto Serif CJK TC,Noto Serif CJK TC SemiBold
Noto Serif CJK KR
Noto Serif CJK JP
Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC Medium
Noto Serif CJK SC
Noto Sans Mono CJK TC
WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬微米黑,文泉驿等宽微米黑
Noto Sans CJK JP
Noto Sans CJK HK
Noto Sans CJK KR
Noto Serif CJK KR,Noto Serif CJK KR Black
AR PL UKai TW
Noto Sans CJK SC
Noto Sans Mono CJK SC
Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC Black
Noto Sans Mono CJK KR
Noto Sans Mono CJK JP
Noto Sans Mono CJK HK
Noto Sans Mono CJK JP
Noto Sans CJK JP,Noto Sans CJK JP Black
Noto Serif CJK KR,Noto Serif CJK KR Medium
Noto Sans Mono CJK HK
Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Medium
Noto Sans CJK JP,Noto Sans CJK JP Light
Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC SemiBold
Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC Light
Noto Sans Mono CJK KR
Noto Sans CJK HK,Noto Sans CJK HK Medium
Noto Serif CJK KR,Noto Serif CJK KR Light
Noto Sans CJK JP,Noto Sans CJK JP DemiLight
AR PL UMing CN
Noto Sans CJK KR
AR PL UMing TW
Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Light
Noto Sans CJK HK
Noto Serif CJK KR
Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP ExtraLight
Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC Black
Noto Sans CJK JP
Noto Serif CJK TC
Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC Thin
Noto Serif CJK TC
AR PL UMing HK
Noto Serif CJK TC,Noto Serif CJK TC ExtraLight
Noto Serif CJK JP
Noto Sans CJK TC
Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP Medium
Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Black
Noto Sans Mono CJK TC
Noto Sans Mono CJK SC
Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Thin
Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC DemiLight
Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC Light
AR PL UMing TW MBE
Noto Serif CJK KR,Noto Serif CJK KR ExtraLight
Noto Sans CJK TC
AR PL UKai HK
AR PL UKai TW MBE
Droid Sans
Noto Sans CJK JP,Noto Sans CJK JP Medium
Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC DemiLight
Noto Sans CJK KR,Noto Sans CJK KR Light
Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC Medium
Noto Sans CJK HK,Noto Sans CJK HK Light
Noto Serif CJK TC,Noto Serif CJK TC Light
Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP Light
Noto Serif CJK JP,Noto Serif CJK JP Black
Noto Sans CJK JP,Noto Sans CJK JP Thin
Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC ExtraLight
Noto Sans CJK KR,Noto Sans CJK KR DemiLight
Noto Serif CJK KR,Noto Serif CJK KR SemiBold
Noto Sans CJK SC
Noto Sans CJK HK,Noto Sans CJK HK Thin
Noto Sans CJK KR,Noto Sans CJK KR Thin
Noto Sans CJK HK,Noto Sans CJK HK Black
Noto Serif CJK TC,Noto Serif CJK TC Black
Noto Sans CJK KR,Noto Sans CJK KR Black
```

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use for the search?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tested by Evince 3.28.4, Adobe Reader 9, Atril 1.20.1, they are the same.